# how to get data attributes of dynamically generated element

Tags: jquery

while throwing dynamic content (through AJAX) from server, i have following response.

```
<a data-contentid="1">Some content</a> ...
```

i have binded the click event using [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/). The problem is in my click event, i am unable to 
get data attributes, so manually attaching is not an option for my case. any ideas?

**Example code:**

```
 $('a.delContent').live("click",function () {

            var cid= jQuery.data(this, "contentid");

            alert(cid);  //undefined
            return false;
        }
           );
```

Comment: Post the code you're using to try and retrieve the data.

Comment: Is the click event getting triggered. Which browser you are using

Comment: @Abdul Kader yes click event are triggered

Comment: @Andy E posted the code.

Comment: @Adeel is that should be var cid= jQuery.data(this, "data-contentid");

Comment: @Abdul Kader thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this inside your click event handler:

```
$(this).data('contentId')
```

Works in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Mk2zy/

Comment: The JSFiddle example isn't dynamic, it's using a plain html link

Comment: @FranciscoCaviano The issue with the OP's code had nothing to do with dynamic content.

Comment: @DarthJDG , OP clearly states "dynamically generated element" in his question.

Comment: @AlphaMale The question wasn't about generating dynamic content or bind handlers, but how to get the data attribute. The callback for live still executes in the context for the clicked element, so the solution does answer the question, regardless of the exact implementation of the example. If the OP would have shared more code, I would have used it in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

try this....

```
var attrValue = $(serverresponse).find('<a>').attr('data-contentId');
alert(attrValue );
```

Comment: That should work, but the ".data()" function also fetches those - and you leave off the "data-" prefix.