# Jquery newer versions - not able to get data-contentId value

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I was looking at this stackoverflow question
[how to get data attributes of dynamically generated element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5831815/how-to-get-data-attributes-of-dynamically-generated-element)

which led me to this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Mk2zy/

But for some reason - it wasn't working on my code. Then I checked the Jquery version - and the fiddle uses 1.5.2 - So on the fiddle if I update the jquery version to anything above 1.5.2 - it doesn't return the value anymore - it returns undefined.

Am I missing something simple here
Thanks for looking in

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `data-contentid` (in the jQuery script only, see below), all lowercase, as defined by the [W3 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes). The jQuery developers may have overlooked that requirement and resolved it for later versions.

> **Note:** All attributes on HTML elements in HTML documents get
>   ASCII-lowercased automatically, so the restriction on ASCII uppercase
>   letters doesn't affect such documents.

The above statement translates to: If there are uppercase letters in `data-*` attributes, they are automatically changed to lowercase, in the HTML, not scripts. This is why `$('data-contentId')` is undefined, because `data-contentId` in the HTML was changed to `data-contentid`.

Comment: Yes; and here is the updated fiddle to work with 1.7.2: http://jsfiddle.net/Mk2zy/43/

Comment: You can add this to your's answer: _" **Note:** All attributes on HTML elements in HTML documents get ASCII-lowercased automatically, so the restriction on ASCII uppercase letters doesn't affect such documents.
"_